# Hook wiggle-bone to empty

Tags: bones, empty, hook-modifier

[image]

The image is from the "wiggle bone addon".
The bones are hooked by empties, to mimic a rope physic.
What is the command to hook empties to bones ?

Comment: Hello could you please describe what you want to do a bit more? It is very vague for the moment